# CSS style rule for child elements

Tags: css, background-color

For a structure like below

```
<div class="container">
<div class="headers">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="header"></div>
  ...
</div>
<div class="contents">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  ...
</div>
</div>
```

I am applying a css style like below but seems the background color gets applied only to the headers and not the content(Style is applied during hover event)

```
.container .header,.content{background-color:#55bbee;font-weight:700;color:#fff}
```

I am certainly sure it's a mistake with the selector, but where is the mistake puzzles me.I could do this and work happily but how to do it in single line

```
.container .header{background-color:#55bbee;font-weight:700;color:#fff}
.container .content{background-color:#55bbee;font-weight:700;color:#fff}
```

Comment: there is missing `s`. either change class name to `content` and `header`

Comment: It's not clear, from your usage of the word "child", whether you're trying to style your `.headers` and `.contents` elements, or their nested `.header` and `.content` elements.

Comment: @BoltClock Sorry should have specified that too, i am styling the **content, header** and not the parent(contents, headers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know you can't group selectors. You have to reference `.container` twice

```
.container .header, .container .content { 
  background-color:#55bbee; font-weight:700; color:#fff
}
```

Comment: i get to do this? `.container .headers .header,.container .contents .content{/* some coloe*/}` there is no shorter way than specifying `.container` for each selection ?

Comment: You are right, there is no shorter way than specifying `.container` twice. You can work around this using LESS, but with pure CSS you will have to go with this.

Comment: If you want it short, use: `.container > div > div {/* style */}` - With this you would reference the header and content divs, but all divs inside divs inside the container class too!

Comment: There is no need for added complexity of selectors in the given case. If it helped, then there was something else on the page that was overriding the setting with the simple selector `.content`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course:

```
.container .header, .container .content {background-color:#55bbee;font-weight:700;color:#fff}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container .headers .header, 
.container .contents .content{background-color:#55bbee;font-weight:700;color:#fff}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code given works just fine, if you have some content in the elements so that any background is shown in the first place.

The problem is elsewhere, in the parts of code not shown.